# Spark writes out `saveAsTextFile` in a Row() format

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to copy these files over from S3 to Redshift, and they are all in the format of Row(column1=value, column2=value,...), which obviously causes issues.  How do I get a dataframe to write out in normal csv?

I'm calling it like this:

```
# final_data.rdd.saveAsTextFile(
    #     path=r's3n://inst-analytics-staging-us-standard/spark/output',
    #     compressionCodecClass='org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec'
    # )
```

I've also tried writing out with the `spark-csv` module, and it seems like it ignores any of the computations I did, and just formats the original parquet file as a csv and dumps it out.

I'm calling that like this:

```
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('results')
```

Comment: The spark-csv approach should work. Maybe you should call `write` on your `final_data` DataFrame?

Comment: Derp that was totally the problem, and I had just figured that out;)  Thanks for pointing it out though!  I'll give you credit for the answer if you make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spark-csv approach is a good one and should be working. It seems by looking at your code that you are calling `df.write` on the original DataFrame `df` and that's why it's ignoring your transformations. To work properly, maybe you should do:

```
final_data = # Do your logic on df and return a new DataFrame        
final_data.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('results')
```